# ¿Cómo personalizar Listas en HTML y CSS?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3

Pues eso me gustaría personalizar los puntos que aparecen en las listas de tipo "ul" en HTML, poner una imagen, cambiar la forma u otra cosa similar. Poder personalizarlo a mi gusto.

- Lista
- Lista
- Lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la propiedad **list-style** y pasandole una url con tu imagen personalizada, podes usar distintos formatos, png, gif:

```
ul {
    list-style: square inside url("tu-imagen.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta amigo, era exactamente lo que buscaba. Gracias.